# How to make the countdown edit instead of messaging one by one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a countdown command, here is my code so far:

```
let count = args[1]

const counter = setInterval(() => {
  if (count > 0) {
    message.channel.send(count)
    count--
  } else {
    clearInterval(counter)
  }
}, 1000)
```

Right now, the timer sends the numbers like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want it only in one message, then edits itself on discord.

Here is how to edit in Discord.JS (example) :

```
   message.channel.send('hi').then(m => {

     m.edit('edited!')
    })
```

Any idea how?

Comment: `m.edit(count)` ?

Comment: @Elitezen Doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do

```js
let count = args[1]
let CountDownMessage;
const counter = setInterval(async () => {
  if (count == args[1]) { //For the first time only
    await message.channel.send(count).then( msg => { CountDownMessage = msg }
    count -- ;
  }else if (count > 0) {
    CountDownMessage.edit(count);
    count -- ;
  } else {
    CountDownMessage.edit("Time's up");
    clearInterval(counter);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Now you don't have to create a function each time

Comment: Keep in mind, timer messages are considered API spam since an API call is made every second, this could lead to suspension if continuex

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by async/await, this is how:-

```
    msg = await message.channel.send('1');
function intervalFunc() {
   msg.edit('2');
}
function twoFunc() {
   msg.edit('3');
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 1000);
setInterval(twoFunc, 2000)
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: There's better methods to update a timer than hardcoding 2 functions

Comment: @Elitezen it's on author to be creative, you can also use for function and use variables. That was just an example...